# How to subset a list of data.frames?

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames and want to subset a part of the dataframes.
In this case, I want to subset the `rainfall` and `yield` in `sublist1 and sublist2` of `mainlist` and create a new list called `mainlist_new`.

But I am facing this error `Error in mainlist[[1]][[, 2:3]] : incorrect number of subscripts`.

Any ideas and thoughts?

here is `code` and created `data`

```
> df1 <- data.frame(station = c("MADA1", "MADA2", "MADA3", "MADA4", "MADA5"),
+                  rainfall = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20),
+                  yield = c(2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000))
> df2 <- df1
> df3 <- df1
> 
> list_1 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
> 
> list_2 <- list(df1, df2, df3)
> 
> mainlist <- list(list_1, list_2)
> names(mainlist) <- c("sublist1", 'sublist2')
> names(mainlist[[1]]) <- c("station", "rainfall", "yield")
> names(mainlist[[2]]) <-  c("station", "rainfall", "yield")
> 
> names(mainlist)
[1] "sublist1" "sublist2"
> names(mainlist[[1]])
[1] "station"  "rainfall" "yield"   
> 
> # subset `rainfall` and `yield` is sublist1 and sublist2 and create a a new list
> mainlist_new <- list()
> mainlist_new[[1]] <- mainlist[[1]][[,2:3]] 
Error in mainlist[[1]][[, 2:3]] : incorrect number of subscripts
> mainlist_new[[2]] <- mainlist[[2]][[,2:3]] 
Error in mainlist[[2]][[, 2:3]] : incorrect number of subscripts
>
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally create an example with a too deeply nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to subset the `list` elements based on names

```
mainlist_new <- lapply(mainlist, `[`, c("rainfall", "yield"))
```

-output

```
> str(mainlist_new)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ rainfall:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ station : chr [1:5] "MADA1" "MADA2" "MADA3" "MADA4" ...
  .. ..$ rainfall: num [1:5] 0 5 10 15 20
  .. ..$ yield   : num [1:5] 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000
  ..$ yield   :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ station : chr [1:5] "MADA1" "MADA2" "MADA3" "MADA4" ...
  .. ..$ rainfall: num [1:5] 0 5 10 15 20
  .. ..$ yield   : num [1:5] 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ rainfall:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ station : chr [1:5] "MADA1" "MADA2" "MADA3" "MADA4" ...
  .. ..$ rainfall: num [1:5] 0 5 10 15 20
  .. ..$ yield   : num [1:5] 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000
  ..$ yield   :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ station : chr [1:5] "MADA1" "MADA2" "MADA3" "MADA4" ...
  .. ..$ rainfall: num [1:5] 0 5 10 15 20
  .. ..$ yield   : num [1:5] 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subset a `list` by `index` at multiple positions you can use the single square brackets `[` instead of double `[[`. Then it should behave as you expect. The difference between these subsetting operators is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el) and [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators).

In your example, all you need to do is change `mainlist_new[[1]] <- mainlist[[1]][[,2:3]]` to `mainlist_new[[1]] <- mainlist[[1]][2:3]`.

Simple example here:

```r
# create list
l <- as.list(1:4)
# subset list by index
l[2:3]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>